# Probability of getting k different colored balls from an urn with K different colors of balls, each color has the same number of balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, sampling, stirling-numbers

**TLDR:**

Let's say I have an urn with $n$ balls, with $K$ different colors of balls, where each color has the same number of balls: $\frac{n}{K}$. Given I reach into the urn and grab a ball (without replacement) $m$ times, what is the probability of getting $k$ different colors of balls?

**Further explanation:**

Example: I have an urn with $GGRRBBYY = n = 8$ number of balls, with $K = 4$ different colors of balls (Green, Red, Blue Yellow). What is the probability of me getting exactly $k = 3$ different colors of balls given I grab $m = 5$ balls from the urn.

Success:
$$YGGBB$$

Failure:
$$YRGBB$$

I want to find a way to solve this for any value of $m$,$k$,$K$,$n$.

This is essentially a more complicated version of figuring out the probability of $m$ balls falling into $k \leq n$ bins, for the 'balls into bins' question ($m$ balls in total, $n$ bins in total). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/72351/901223) (in equation 1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2844991/901223) (at the end of the answer) solutions to solve the easier 'balls into bins' variant. The answer is:

$${n \choose k}\frac{\left\{\begin{array}{l}
m \\
k
\end{array}\right\} k !}{n^{m}}$$

I am looking for a similar solution to the urn problem I have stated. I believe using a [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution) could give me the answer, although I think this will be complicated and extremely costly to compute. Basically, my idea is to count all possible combinations that exactly $k$ different colors of balls can be selected by applying the multivariate hypergeometric distribution formula many times. That is:

$$\frac{\sum {\frac{n}{K} \choose w_1}{\frac{n}{K} \choose w_2} \cdots {\frac{n}{K} \choose w_K}}{{n \choose m}}$$

The summation above denotes summing over all possible combinations of $w_i$ for all $i$, where $w_1 + w_2 \cdots + w_K = m$ and there are only $k$ number of $w_i$ that are greater than $0$.  (excuse me on my potentially poor use of notation).

There must be a better way of formulating this... but if not, it would be nice of someone to suggest a fairly efficient way of computing this (by compute, I mean: some computer code that will calculate it for me). Or if someone could provide an approximation or a lower bound via a much more compact/simple formulation, that would also be wonderful! Perhaps modelling the problem as a 'balls into bin' scenario is a 'good enough' approximation...?

[This similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288248/probability-of-choosing-different-colors-when-there-are-more-colors-than-balls-p) might also be inspiration for a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Pick $K-k$ colors and compute the likelihood of avoiding those colors.  Then multiply by $\binom Kk$ to get the likelihood of no more than $k$ colors.  Do it again for the likelihood of excluding $k+1$ colors.  Subtract one answer from the other to get the likelihood of excluding exactly $k$ colors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; it is clever yet simple! I noticed a couple grammar/logic errors. I think this is what you meant to say: "Pick $K−k$ colors and compute the probability of avoiding those colors. Then multiply by ${K \choose k}$ to get the probability of picking no more than k colors. Repeat the previous step to get the probability of avoiding $K - (k-1)$ colors (picking no more than $k-1$ colors). Subtract the second probability from the first probability to get the probability of picking exactly k colors."

Comment: hmmm... I'm a bit confused now. I tried calculating it the way you suggested and I think there is an issue with your method. Multiplying by ${K \choose k}$ results in over-counting (resulting in a probability greater than 1 in some instances).

Comment: You need to multiply the likelihood of avoiding $K-k$ *specific* colors by $\binom Kk$ in order to determine the likelihood of avoiding all possible sets of colors of that size.  I suggest you edit the question to show this new work so we can see where the problem lies.

Comment: [Cross-posted at CrossValidated here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/582906/1352), with currently one answer masquerading as a comment. Sometimes CV *is* more useful for probability and combinatorics questions...